# How to open a new tab in firefox

Tags: .net

I currently have 5 text boxes and a button on my form. When I click the button, I'd like my application to open a firefox tab for each textbox like so:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com/" & textbox1.text)
End Sub
```

So that code was just for the one textbox, but I'd like it be able to open a second tab for the second text box. Like so:

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com/" & textbox1.text)
    'How do I get this to open a new tab?
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com/" & textbox2.text)
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Put a space between your params. you can start firefox from the command line like: `firefox google.com stackoverflow.com` and it will launch with those 2 tabs

Comment: I tried         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com", "www.google.com") and it's giving me a build error.

Comment: That's not the signature to pass multiple parameters. You need to pass them all as the second parameter separated by spaces.

Comment: Okay. I tried         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox" "www.google.com" "www.google.com") and         System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com" "www.google.com") and both are not working. I get a build error that says I need a comma in there.

Comment: Those are two separate strings and a syntax error. You need one string. `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Firefox", "www.google.com www.google.com")`.

Comment: You're a magician! Thank you!